# Mega Defender Installation Help

Tags: windows-7, mega-defender

I have an old freeware game on my older MS Windows 7 (32bit) computer that I would like to move to my new Windows 7 (64bit) computer.  It's called Mega Defender and used to be downloadable [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100904221553/http://www.rubicondev.com/?page_id=30).

[image: Mega Defender screen shot]

I contacted the author and he promptly responded but told me he didn't have it anymore.  It would be great if someone still had the installation file out there.

Otherwise, is there a way to move the program to my new computer.  I did copy over the files in the program directory, but when I execute the program I only get a quick black flash on my monitor and then the program is exited.

None of the compatibility options were set on the old computer and setting them on the new one didn't help.

Copying the register keys over didn't do a difference either.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Rubicon\MegaDefender]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Mega Defender"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Rubicon\MegaDefender]
"SaveGame"=hex:01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,32,\
  00,00,00,32,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00
```

(Forum with some old developer discussion: http://forums.indiegamer.com/showthread.php?15482-Mega-Defender )

It would be cool to get this game working on the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

If all environment settings (comp mode, colour depth) are correct, all game files and all registry keys have been copied over correctly (I take it you made sure of that), then it's most likely an architecture problem.

In some cases, 32bit games just plain refuse to work on 64bit machines, then you'd probably be out of luck. You could however still try setting up a (32 bit) virtual machine and running the game within.